# Amazon EC2 - Apache server restart issue

Tags: linux, apache, amazon-ec2

When i run this command

> sudo /etc/init.d/httpd restart

it gives below error

Stopping httpd:                  [FAILED]

Starting httpd: (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs   [FAILED]

---

i checked running programs at port 80 by using

netstat -lnp | grep :80  (it gives below output)

tcp        0      0 :::80          :::*             LISTEN      21739/httpd

---

why i am not able to stop stop apache by using sudo /etc/init.d/httpd restart?

below commands work without issue

sudo apachectl stop

sudo apachectl start

i am using linux micro instance of amazon ec2

Answer (score 26):

I ran into this problem when I installed apache from source, but then tried to run

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

which was using a pre-installed version of apache.  The stop directive in /etc/init.d/httpd was not removing the httpd.pid file that was created when starting the source-installed version of apache.

To determine if this is also the reason for your problem, find where the httpd.pid file is getting set when you run

```
$ sudo apachectl start
```

If you installed from source and apache2 is living in /usr/local/apache2, then the httpd.pid file should get created in /usr/local/apache2/logs.  When you stop apache by running

```
$ sudo apachectl stop
```

this file should get removed. So to test if the httpd.pid file is causing your problem, start apache by calling

```
$ sudo apachectl start
```

and locate the httpd.pid file.  Then try stopping apache by using

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/httpd stop
```

If the original httpd.pid file is still present, then that is why apache is unable to start when you use

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/httpd start
```

To get my /etc/init.d/httpd file to work correctly, I explicitly put the call to apachectl in the start and stop methods:

```
#!/bin/bash
# /etc/init.d/httpd
#
# Path to the apachectl script, server binary, and short-form for messages. 
apachectl=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl 
httpd=/usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd 
pid=/usr/local/apache2/logs/httpd.pid 
prog=httpd 
RETVAL=0

start() {
    echo -n $"Starting $prog: "
    $apachectl -k start
    RETVAL=$?
    echo
    return $RETVAL
}
stop() {
    echo -n $"Stopping $prog: "
    $apachectl -k stop
    RETVAL=$?
    echo
}
```

Answer (score 18):

I tried this and it works:

1. sudo  fuser -k -n tcp 80
2. sudo  service httpd start

Hope this will help you!

Cheers

Comment: This was incredibly helpful. Thanks :)

Comment: I use "sudo service httpd restart" and this will first try to shutdown Apache. If running it will end the process, if off this attempt will show as a failure to end the process in service restart's output. After the attempt to stop the process, the attempt to start will initiate. This command has never failed to restart an Apache server unless there were fatal errors, which will display in the service restart's output messages.

Answer (score 2):

I feel its better to kill the process itself, find out the process id and kill it and then do a fresh start, it should work fine

Answer (score 1):

I have had this issue very rarely over the last couple years with a server I've been managing.  Unfortunately, if you are getting FAILED after trying to restart, the process that's managing the connection on port 80 won't release it's hold on that port.

I would try a full "sudo /etc/init.d/httpd stop" wait for that to finish or fail.

If that doesn't fix it you'll have to restart the server completely.  Hopefully, it's configured to start everything up automatically on restart, but that isn't guaranteed.

"apachectl" is also great tool for Apache, but it may not be on this server, it depends on the install and linux distro used.

If after rebooting the server, apache still fails to start, something bad has happened.  I'd consider pulling all the website and conf files for creating a new server at that point, but the apache start, and then failed message output should give you some idea of where to look in the Logs about why it cannot start.