# 48)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80

Tags: php, macos, apache, localhost

I get a apache error when I try access to anything folder or file, it returns `Http Not found` or `Forbidden`
I am trying restart and start apache

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

output:

```
(48)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(48)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

I am trying stop it

```
sudo apachectl stop
```

output

```
httpd (no pid file) not running
```

I run `sudo lsof -i:80`

output:

```
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME

    httpd    8904 root    5u  IPv6 0x21884d81f1597d8f      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
    httpd    9012 _www    5u  IPv6 0x21884d81f1597d8f      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
    httpd   12726 _www    5u  IPv6 0x21884d81f1597d8f      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
    httpd   12731 _www    5u  IPv6 0x21884d81f1597d8f      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
    httpd   12732 _www    5u  IPv6 0x21884d81f1597d8f      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

Any idea to solve that ?

Useful information:

```
OS X El Capitan
```

Comment: Anything listening on port 80, have you checked? Perhaps with netstat?

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) or [unix.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Amazon EC2 - Apache server restart issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9557503/amazon-ec2-apache-server-restart-issue)

Answer (score 61):

In my Mac with Mojave (10.14.1) suddenly Apache couldn't give to serve ipv4 anymore, then gave me ERROR 403. I tried to kill all apache (sudo killall httpd)... checking de PID's on (sudo lsof | grep AMP | grep apache)... even didn't work... just ipv6 was available... still ERROR 403.

What works for me: Disable OSX's built-in Apache server.

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
```

After that:

```
sudo apachectl -k restart
```

Be happy :)

Comment: Worked like a charm! Removing apachectl from autoload - worked.

Comment: THANK YOU, I went all through the apache setup until I found this error changing sphp version. I am on mohave 10.14.3

Comment: wow. Thank you. Was trying so many things and finally this works :)

Comment: Worked for me too! Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

Try

```
sudo netstat -ltnp | grep ':80'
```

Output: tcp6  0   0 :::80       :::*      LISTEN      1500/apache2

```
sudo kill 1500
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: this one work for me, after several hours of headache finally works perfectly fine, I feel foolish right now haha. thanks for the solutions

Answer (score 16):

This one helped me:

Please edit httpd.conf file.

```
/usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf
```

And replace

```
Listen 80
```

with

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
```

Restart apache

```
sudo apachectl -k restart
```

Comment: I tried to identify what's blocking port 80 with the commands mentioned in the other answers, but I found no blockers. But your solution worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: I ran into this for a local https setup, updated from Listen 443 to Listen 127.0.0.1:443, similar to Evan's note below. - thank you @Nuzil

Answer (score 10):

One of a couple of things could be happening:

1. You have a different version of apache running. You can make sure that you're using the correct one by running `which apachectl`. As an example, I also have two versions of apache `/usr/sbin/apachectl` and `/usr/local/bin/apachectl`
2. You're not running `apachectl start` as root, although it appears that you are.
3. You can run `sudo lsof -i:80` to see what's binding that port currently

Comment: Ahh, so you have `httpd` running. I forget when, but macOS had an update that changed the directory of the apache it's using and renamed the process. It messed up my local development environment quite a bit.

Comment: you can run `sudo httpd -k stop` to stop the service and then attempt to restart apache normally. I would run `which apachectl` to find out which version you're using 

The old location of the apache config files was in `/etc/apache2` but apple has since moved it to `/usr/local/etc/httpd`

You can find the server config file with:
`apachectl -V | grep SERVER_CONFIG_FILE`

Comment: The lsof put me on the right track, somehow I had nginx installed apparently which snagged the port.

Answer (score 7):

this error ocurs because apache server listen by deafult in port 80 so another service or program is using that port and apache canot start.

The solution is identify what program or service is using that port an then close, disable or unistall it.

to identify you can run netstat

```
sudo netstat -ltnp | grep ':80'
```

or

```
sudo lsof -i:80
```

in my case i have installed nginx and apache at the same time and both uses the port 80.

**Temporary Solution:** Stop or kill the service, program, etc.

**Permanent Solution:**

1. Change the port of apache server in config file
   /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
2. Uninstall the service or program that uses port 80.

in my case I needed both so I decided to temporarily fix it by disabling the service with:

```
systemctl stop MyServiceName.service
```

If it is a service otherwise use kill command.

Answer (score 4):

I had my configuration set up this way before as well, and ran into the same problem after I upgraded OSX this last time. I tried to find ANYTHING that was listening on either port 80 or 443 and couldn't find a thing anywhere.  It took me a while but finally found another article that described a fix that actually worked.  Keep in mind I'm using a homebrew install and have unloaded the default apache2 install that comes with Mac OSX.

Here's what I had before in my httpd.conf:

```
Listen 80
```

and I had something similar in ssl.conf

```
Listen 443 https
```

I had to alter my httpd.conf file to use a ServerName of localhost and Listen on 0.0.0.0:80, and same for ssl.conf but 0.0.0.0:443 https

httpd.conf:

```
ServerName localhost
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
```

and ssl.conf

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:443 https
```

Once I tried starting it again, everything was happy.  Hope that helps!  I would link to the article but I'm having trouble finding it again!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks as if httpd is already running. To check run

lsof -i TCP:80
COMMAND  PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
httpd    281   root    3u  IPv6  19479      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
....

So kill httpd and do what you want

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32252884)

Answer (score 0):

If you've recently done a software update and you renamed or removed any of the default files in /etc/httpd/conf.d/   go have a look there. You might have duplicate directives because the package manager re-installed them.

In my case, I prefixed the files with numbers so I could control the load order... but an OS update re-installed the original files so
I had two files with "Listen 443" in them which conflicted and wasn't caught by the syntax check. Removing the os files fixed the issue.

(This time I left them but made them empty so the conflict will be displayed on re-install or update)