# I tried to start laravel project on linux

Tags: php, laravel, apache, httpd.conf, amazon-linux

Suddenly... my website happens timeout-error.
it seems not process does not work.
How should I restart the project...

php-fpm.conf

```
$  service apache2 restart
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart apache2.service
Failed to restart apache2.service: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .service files
See system logs and 'systemctl status apache2.service' for details.
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-30-200 laravel6]$ systemctl status httpd.service
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service.d
           └─php-fpm.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-04-12 09:12:06 ; 1min 48s ago
     Docs: man:httpd.service(8)
  Process: 4123 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 4123 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "Reading configuration..."
```

```
.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal httpd[4123]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal httpd[4123]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal httpd[4123]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal httpd[4123]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

```
$ systemctl restart php7.0-fpm.service 
Failed to restart php7.0-fpm.service: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .service files
See system logs and 'systemctl status php7.0-fpm.service' for details.
```

```
$  systemctl stop httpd
Failed to stop httpd.service: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .service files
See system logs and 'systemctl status httpd.service' for details.
```

Comment: it seems you have 2  config file listen in same port

Comment: How should fix the config file? What config prevent staring process?

Answer (score 0):

@nuzil answer here,

[48)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51047700/48address-already-in-use-ah00072-make-sock-could-not-bind-to-address-80)

Please edit httpd.conf file.

```
/usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf
```

And replace

```
Listen 80
```

with

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
```

Restart apache

```
sudo apachectl -k restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you tried use same port in two configuration files, or 80 port used on other service like nginx. Try `sudo lsof -n -i :80 | grep LISTEN` to check process that using 80 port.

Also, you missed the `sudo` command to execute `systemctl` command. Maybe that is permission problem.